# andengine setposition of animatedsprite

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

with andengine I'm trying to create a Footbal Game,
When the ball go in goal and dissapears from the screen, I would like to update score and reposition the ball at the center of the screen.
Update score in working well, but not the reposition.
Here is the code for the ball:

```
    final AnimatedSprite ball;
    final Body bodyBall;
    ball = new AnimatedSprite(centerX, centerY,this.mBallTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    bodyBall = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ball, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
    ball.setUserData(bodyBall);
    ball.animate(200);
    this.mScene.registerTouchArea(ball);
    this.mScene.attachChild(ball);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(ball, bodyBall, true, true));
```

and here the code to check goal:

```
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
        if(UpperGoal.collidesWith(ball)) {
            ScoreA = ScoreA+1;
            ScoreText.setText(ScoreA+" - " + ScoreB);
            bodyBall.setTransform(new Vector2(CAMERA_WIDTH/2,CAMERA_HEIGHT/2),0);               
            UpperGoal.setColor(1, 0, 0);
```

I try also bodyBall.setPosition(100,100,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Body class has no method setPosition.
To set new coordinates, use

```java
bodyBall.setTransform(new Vector2(x/32,y/32), 0);
```

you need to divide by 32 because box2d does not operates in pixels

Comment: 32 is a constant PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT in org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.util.constants

Answer (score 0):

setTransform is working, but it's value should be divided by the pixel to meter ratio, which by default is 32.0f or you can use PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT. Also note that the setTransform use the center of the body as anchorcenter so if you are using the GLES2 branch (not GLES2-AnchorCenter) you should subtract the half of the width and height of your sprite, e.g:

```
yourBody.setTransform((yourNewX - yourSprite.getWidth() / 2) / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, (yourNewY - yourSprite.getHeight() / 2) / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, yourBody.getAngle());
```